# Call a function based upon an integer

Tags: php, mysql, variables, calendar

I have a php table that displays the days of the month in a table:

```
    //count up the days, untill we've done all of them in the month

 while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) 

 { 

 echo "<td> $day_num </td>"; 

 $day_num++; 

 $day_count++;
```

I have a second table that calls a separate query for each day of the month:

```
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php do { ?>
        <?php echo $row_apr1['appt_time']; ?> <em><?php echo $row_apr1['nickname']; ?></em><br>
        <?php } while ($row_apr1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($apr1)); ?></td>
    <td><?php do { ?>
        <?php echo $row_apr2['appt_time']; ?> <em><?php echo $row_apr2['nickname']; ?></em><br>
        <?php } while ($row_apr2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($apr2)); ?></td>
    <td><?php do { ?>
        <?php echo $row_apr3['appt_time']; ?> <em><?php echo $row_apr3['nickname']; ?></em><br>
        <?php } while ($row_apr3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($apr3)); ?></td>
    <td><?php do { ?>
        <?php echo $row_apr4['appt_time']; ?> <em><?php echo $row_apr4['nickname']; ?></em><br>
        <?php } while ($row_apr4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($apr4)); ?></td>
    <td><?php do { ?>
        <?php echo $row_apr5['appt_time']; ?> <em><?php echo $row_apr5['nickname']; ?></em><br>
        <?php } while ($row_apr5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($apr5)); ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Is there a way I can merge the code together into one table, like using the $day_num value to call the query code?

Example:  April 4th - $day_num would be = 4 and display a 4 in the table.  But then can't I use php concatenation or something to call the code:

```
<br><?php echo $row_apr4['appt_time']; ?> <em><?php echo $row_apr4['nickname']; ?></em><br>
            <?php } while ($row_apr4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($apr4)); ?>
```

Sorry if this has been done before a million times.  I've been searching and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to change your var names. Instead of `$row_apr4` you could consider using an array `$row_apr[4]`, or for multiple months even `$row['apr'][4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable variables or `$$` option. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
<td>
    <?php 
    $variable_name = 'apr' . $day_num;
    do { ?>
            <?php echo $row['appt_time']; ?>
            <em><?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></em><br>
    <?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($$variable_name)); ?>
</td>
```

Not sure this is the best option for you but based off the code you have supplied it is a possible solution.

FYI you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated.